# How to solve the "R0 invalid mem access 'inv'" error when loading an eBPF file object

Tags: linux-kernel, clang, jit, bpf

I'm trying to load an eBPF object in the kernel with `libbpf`, with no success, getting the error specified in the title. But let me show how simple my BPF `*_kern.c` is.

```
SEC("entry_point_prog")
int entry_point(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{
    int act = XDP_DROP;
    int rc, i = 0;
    struct global_vars *globals;
    struct ip_addr addr = {};
    struct some_key key = {};
    void *temp;

    globals = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&globals_map, &i);
    if (!globals)
        return XDP_ABORTED;

    rc = some_inlined_func(ctx, &key);

    addr = key.dst_ip;
    temp = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&some_map, &addr);

    switch(rc)
    {
    case 0:
        if(temp)
        {
            // no rocket science here ...
        } else
            act = XDP_PASS;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return act;  // this gives the error
    //return XDP_<whatever>;  // this works fine
}
```

More precisely, the `libbpf` error log is the following:

```
105: (bf) r4 = r0
106: (07) r4 += 8
107: (b7) r8 = 1
108: (2d) if r4 > r3 goto pc+4
 R0=inv40 R1=inv0 R2=inv(id=0,umax_value=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R3=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R4=inv48 R5=inv512 R6=inv1 R7=inv17 R8=inv1 R10=fp0,call_-1 fp-16=0 fp-32=0 fp-40=0
109: (69) r3 = *(u16 *)(r0 +2)
R0 invalid mem access 'inv'
```

I really don't see any problem here. I mean, this is so so simple, and yet it breaks. Why shouldn't this work? What am I missing? Either the verifier went crazy, or I'm doing something very stupid.

Comment: Could you try with a u64 return type?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce with a minimal example. It looks like at some point the program tries to store into `r3` a value stored at `*(r0 + 2)`, at a time when `r0` is a scalar value. `r0` is typically used as a return value, do you use any BPF helper? Or since the problem seems related to `act`, do you update `act` in one way or another in the rest of your program?

Comment: @pchaigno I tried with u64, nothing changed :( ...
@Qeole `act` is updated in that `else` branch only... I'm updating the code so you may hopefully have a better idea of what's happening

Comment: My bad, the int return type is alright! I couldn't reproduce the bug either. If you try to run the exact code you gave us, with the empty if body, do you still have the error? What versions of the kernel and LLVM are you using?

Comment: kernel 4.18.10 ... `clang` and `llc` at 8.0.0 which at the moment isn't out yet, so it's not stable. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I had an issue with clang-8 not long ago, you might want to try with -7 or -6.0 if you can. Other than this I don't see anything that looks wrong with the program.

Comment: Tried with llvm-7, same exact error. I really have no clue what to do now :(

Comment: Could you post the complete code (complete C kernel code + userspace code)? Maybe XDP_DROP is weirdly defined or something tries to write to the stack directly. Given the bug, it's going to be hard to debug without all the details. (If there are part you want to keep private, you can remove them and check that they don't affect the bug.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so, after 3 days, more precisely 3 x 8 hrs = 24 hrs, worth of code hunting, I think I've finally found the itching problem.

The problem was in the `some_inlined_func()` all along, it was more tricky then challenging. I'm writing down here a code template explaining the issue, so others could see and hopefully spend less then 24 hrs of headache; I went through hell for this, so stay focused.

```
__alwais_inline static
int some_inlined_func(struct xdp_md *ctx, /* other non important args */)
{
    if (!ctx)
        return AN_ERROR_CODE;

    void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;

    struct ethhdr *eth;
    struct iphdr *ipv4_hdr = NULL;
    struct ipv6hdr *ipv6_hdr = NULL;
    struct udphdr *udph;
    uint16_t ethertype;

    eth = (struct ethhdr *)data;
    if (eth + 1 > data_end)
        return AN_ERROR_CODE;

    ethertype = __constant_ntohs(eth->h_proto);
    if (ethertype == ETH_P_IP)
    {
        ipv4_hdr = (void *)eth + ETH_HLEN;
        if (ipv4_hdr + 1 > data_end)
            return AN_ERROR_CODE;

        // stuff non related to the issue ...
    } else if (ethertype == ETH_P_IPV6)
    {
        ipv6_hdr = (void *)eth + ETH_HLEN;
        if (ipv6_hdr + 1 > data_end)
            return AN_ERROR_CODE;

        // stuff non related to the issue ...
    } else
        return A_RET_CODE_1;

    /* here's the problem, but ... */
    udph = (ipv4_hdr) ? ((void *)ipv4_hdr + sizeof(*ipv4_hdr)) :
            ((void *)ipv6_hdr + sizeof(*ipv6_hdr));
    if (udph + 1 > data_end)
        return AN_ERROR_CODE;

    /* it actually breaks HERE, when dereferencing 'udph' */
    uint16_t dst_port = __constant_ntohs(udph->dest);

    // blablabla other stuff here unrelated to the problem ...

    return A_RET_CODE_2;
}
```

So, why it breaks at that point? I think it's because the verifier assumes `ipv6_hdr` could potentially be `NULL`, which is utterly WRONG because if the execution ever gets to that point, that's only because either `ipv4_hdr` or `ipv6_hdr` has been set (i.e. the execution dies before this point if it's the case of neither IPv4 nor IPv6). So, apparently, the verifier isn't able to infer that. However, there's a catch, it is happy if the validity of also `ipv6_hdr` is explicitly checked, like this:

```
if (ipv4_hdr)
    udph = (void *)ipv4_hdr + sizeof(*ipv4_hdr);
else if (ipv6_hdr)
    udph = (void *)ipv6_hdr + sizeof(*ipv6_hdr);
else return A_RET_CODE_1;  // this is redundant
```

It also works if we do this:

```
// "(ethertype == ETH_P_IP)" instead of "(ipv4_hdr)"
udph = (ethertype == ETH_P_IP) ? ((void *)ipv4_hdr + sizeof(*ipv4_hdr)) :
        ((void *)ipv6_hdr + sizeof(*ipv6_hdr));
```

So, it seems to me there's something strange about the verifier here, because it's not smart enough (maybe neither it needs to be?) to realize that if it ever gets to this point, it's only because `ctx` refers either an IPv4 or IPv6 packet.

How does all of this explain the complaining over `return act;` within the `entry_point()`? Simple, just bear with me. The `some_inlined_func()` isn't changing `ctx`, and its remaining args aren't used either by `entry_point()`. Thus, in case of returning `act`, as it depends on the `some_inlined_func()` outcome, the `some_inlined_func()` gets executed, with the verifier complaining at that point. But, in case of returning `XDP_<whatever>`, as the `switch-case` body, and neither the `some_inlined_func()`, doesn't change the internal state of the `entry_point()` program/function, the compiler (with O2) is smart enough to realize that there's no point in producing assembly for `some_inlined_func()` and the whole `switch-case` (that's the O2 optimization over here). Therefore, to conclude, in case of returning `XDP_<whatever>`, the verifier was happy as the problem actually lies into `some_inlined_func()` but the actual produced BPF assembly doesn't have anything of that, so the verifier didn't checked `some_inlined_func()` because there wasn't any in the first place. Makes sense?

Is such BPF "limitation" known? Is out there any document at all stating such known limitations? Because I didn't found any.

Comment: Hi, glad to see you found the issue! I wouldn't think of this as a “limitation”, and no, I'm not aware of any document of the kind. Basically we have to remember that the verifier does not work on `some_inlined_func()` at all, it's never aware of that function but just reasons on a set of eBPF bytecode instructions. If the compiler optimized out your function, the verifier has no way to guess what you intended to do instead... So in that case you may try to compile with `-O0` and analyse the differences, and work with e.g. `llvm-objdump -d` or `-S` to have a look at the generated bytecode.